# Browser native scrollbar with locomotive smooth scrolling library not the custom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the locomotive scroll library for smooth scrolling, The js file of this library creates a custom scrollbar to the body and there is even an option we can disable it.

**See the demo of locomotive library** [codepen demo here](https://codepen.io/D_kingnelson/pen/NWrQewe)

Another demo Look at the page it has a custom scrollbar and I need the default browser native scrollbar.
[Demo](https://tympanus.net/Development/TileScroll/)

The CSS part of this library makes the native scrollbar hidden.

```
html.has-scroll-smooth {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

I need the browser native scrollbar should be there and for that, I made the overflow: auto.

**But it creates extra whitespace.** Is there any way to keep the browser's native scrollbar?

```
html.has-scroll-smooth {
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

**If it is not possible to use the native scroll bar with a locomotive library please suggest an alternate solution for the same result.**

**The tweaks I've made it** [demo](https://codepen.io/shahidali/pen/eYBYZNe)

Comment: Do you want two scrollbars? Where is the extra space added?

Comment: No, I need the browser single native scrollbar.

Comment: So this? `.c-scrollbar { display: none; }`

Comment: please take at both demos I'm able to remove .c-scrollbar but along with that, the native browser creates whitespace.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where the white space is added?

Comment: https://codepen.io/shahidali/pen/eYBYZNe

Comment: That's not a screenshot and I saw that pen.

Comment: If you scroll down the tweaks pen you'll notice.